# in window command how to get value in array via variable

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file

I have encounter a problem in getting array value, the following is my 
code snippets:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set arraynum=0
set count=0
set list[0]=1
For /R %cd%\ %%G IN (*) do (
set filenum=%%G
echo %%G
set list[!arraynum!]=!filenum!
set /a arraynum+=1
)

echo %arraynum%
echo %list%
echo %count%
echo %%list[%count%]%%
pause
```

the result value of %%list[%count%]%% is %list[0]%, not the value of 
filename, it's very strange and is there any way or any instruction to cover
that, thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script)

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have delayed expansion enabled, you can use it to get the array value.

```
echo !list[%count%]!
```

If you didn't have it enabled, you could have used `call` instead.

```
call echo %%list[%count%]%%
```